# Is there an analog for MEV in Polkadot?

Tags: polkadot, mev

Is there maybe something like Collator-MEV, Validator-MEV, …?

Comment: (Tagging as mev as that is what the genre is known as.)

Comment: Maximal extractable value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose it might be best described as CEV (Collator Extracted Value) or VEV (Validator Extracted Value). But I think best would be BAEV (Block Author Extracted Value), since it applies equally to all consensus methods.